# Showing customers who have purchased more than 1 product, but from the same subscription

Tags: sql

I'm trying to find the number of customers who have ordered more than one product, with the same subscription.

I've first selected the count of the `id_customer` from `customer`. Then joined on `subscription` and `order` (on the correct keys). This was done so that I have all the data available to me from all 3 tables. Then grouped by the `id_customer` to get just the unique customers. And lastly filtered to have a `fk_product` (products a customer has) greater than 1.

```
SELECT COUNT(t1.id_customer)
FROM customer t1
INNER JOIN subscription t2 ON t1.id_customer = t2.fk_customer
INNER JOIN order t3 ON t2.id_subscription = t3.fk_subscription
GROUP BY t1.id_customer
HAVING COUNT(t3.fk_product) > 1
```

I'd like to better understand if this is the correct syntax to obtain the data I'm looking for. Since I have `t2.id_subscription` and `t3.fk_subscription` linked, wouldn't this be correct? I'm still getting the wrong output. I'm thinking its perhaps the way I have my scopes, or some subtle aspect of SQL that I'm not using/understanding.

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Why do you have a relationship from product to both subscription and order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two levels of aggregation.  Your data model is a bit hard to follow, but I think:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT so.fk_customer)
FROM (SELECT s.fk_customer, s.id_subscription
      FROM subscription s
           order o
           ON s.id_subscription = o.fk_subscription
      GROUP BY s.fk_customer, s.id_subscription
      HAVING MIN(o.fk_product) <> MAX(o.fk_product)
     ) so
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(distinct s.id_customer)
from (
   SELECT t1.id_customer
   FROM customer t1
   INNER JOIN subscription t2 ON t1.id_customer = t2.fk_customer
   INNER JOIN order t3 ON t2.id_subscription = t3.fk_subscription
   GROUP BY t1.id_customer, t3.fk_subscription
   HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
) s
```